# Load HTML to CefSharp

Tags: c#, html, wpf, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

**Is it possible to bind a string containing HTML to a CefSharp browser?**

I was using a WPF `WebBrowser` like this:

```
<WebBrowser behaviors:WebBrowserSourceBinder.Body="{Binding HtmlsCollectionView/Content}" />
```

This is binding an `ObservableCollection` of HTML strings to the `WebBrowser` using an `attached property` to conclude the binding.

I tried to bind it the same way to the `Address` property of the CefSharp browser but nothing happens:

```
<cefsharp:ChromiumWebBrowser Address="{Binding HtmlsCollectionView/Content}"/>
```

I believe this is due `Address` only really accepts addresses (www.google.com).

**Is it there a way to pass an HTML string to be rendered instead?**

Comment: Not using `xaml`. Address must be a `Url`. You can use the `LoadHtml` method in code, search the source for examples.

Comment: @amaitland I can't find that method on a CefSharp `ChromiumWebBrowser`.

Comment: It's an extension method, in the `CefSharp` namespace. Make sure you search the source for examples, read the `xml` doc as well.

Comment: @amaitland Ok, I found the method under a `WebBrowserExtensions` class. I am trying to call it using a `Behavior` to bind the method to the string but it's not working. Do you know if the CefSharp browser can have `Behaviors`?

Comment: You have to wait for the browser to initialize. Search the `GitHub` project for details.

Comment: I just remembered you can encode `html` into a `data uri` see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/commit/d1d754cf58d94a278ddf497f00dfb233b20ca427#diff-ae22f43defce5876f044e1169a4afe07 for an example, you can probably bind that to `Address` if you encode appropriately.

Comment: Ok, I was hopping this would be as simple as the `WebBrowser`, but it appears I will have to do some reading.

Comment: @amaitland I am probably going to be filling a bug report soon, the rendering is horrible in my project, I think it's due to the fact the browser is inside a `Grid` Column that can be resized by 2 `GridSplitter` on both sides of it.

Comment: If your scaling the control then you should look at https://gitter.im/cefsharp/CefSharp?at=5809847bb17b667961df3359

Comment: Please don't open a bug, there are known issues with scaling in `WPF`, which I have no time/requirement to fix. Someone else will need to contribute.

Comment: By all means contribute some behaviors that make `WPF` implementation easier.

Comment: thanks, I set `RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality"` and now it doesn't look pixelated anymore....but the webpage doesn't tries to fit to the width of the web browser as the regular `WebBrowser` control from WPF does, any advices on this?

Comment: Grab the source, modify the example, see what's going on. Not a scenario I've tested.